# Problem with PHP session and memcached servers

Tags: php, session, memcached

I made a lot of searches on Google, but I couldn't find anything that help me...

I have a PHP Server (Version **7.3.27-1~deb10u1**), and I store PHP session with **memcached** PECL module (v 3.1.4), connected to two servers **Memcached 1.5.6** (mc3, mc4).

Here is the php info of memcached:

```
memcached
memcached support   enabled
Version 3.1.4
libmemcached version    1.0.18
SASL support    yes
Session support yes
igbinary support    yes
json support    yes
msgpack support yes

Directive   Local Value Master Value
memcached.compression_factor    1.3 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold 2000    2000
memcached.compression_type  fastlz  fastlz
memcached.default_binary_protocol   Off Off
memcached.default_connect_timeout   0   0
memcached.default_consistent_hash   Off Off
memcached.serializer    php php
memcached.sess_binary_protocol  On  On
memcached.sess_connect_timeout  0   0
memcached.sess_consistent_hash  On  On
memcached.sess_consistent_hash_type ketama  ketama
memcached.sess_lock_expire  0   0
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait    not set not set
memcached.sess_lock_retries 10  10
memcached.sess_lock_wait    not set not set
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max    2500    2500
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min    150 150
memcached.sess_locking  On  On
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas   1   1
memcached.sess_persistent   Off Off
memcached.sess_prefix   memc.sess.key.  memc.sess.key.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read   Off Off
memcached.sess_remove_failed_servers    Off Off
memcached.sess_sasl_password    no value    no value
memcached.sess_sasl_username    no value    no value
memcached.sess_server_failure_limit 0   0
memcached.store_retry_count 2   2
```

php info about session:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly 1   1
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_samesite None    None
session.cookie_secure   1   1
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.lazy_write  Off Off
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    memcached   memcached
session.save_path   mc3:11211,mc4:11211 mc3:11211,mc4:11211
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.sid_bits_per_character  5   5
session.sid_length  26  26
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies 1   1
session.use_only_cookies    1   1
session.use_strict_mode 1   1
session.use_trans_sid   0
```

Sometimes, I have some 3 different PHP Warnings in the error.log:

```
    PHP Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: memcached (path: mc3:11211,mc4:11211) in ...
```

```
    PHP Warning: session_start(): Unable to clear session lock record in ...
```

```
    PHP Warning: Unknown: error saving session to memcached: SUCCESS in Unknown on line 0
```

mc3 stats from memcached:

```
stats
STAT pid 4605
STAT uptime 26116746
STAT time 1623423688
STAT version 1.5.6
STAT libevent 2.1.8-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 79124.237411
STAT rusage_system 229363.516381
STAT max_connections 1024
STAT curr_connections 6
STAT total_connections 717575493
STAT rejected_connections 0
STAT connection_structures 370
STAT reserved_fds 20
STAT cmd_get 62408739
STAT cmd_set 263762563
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 62374874
STAT get_misses 33865
STAT get_expired 73927
STAT get_flushed 0
STAT delete_misses 69381618
STAT delete_hits 62368677
STAT incr_misses 5084
STAT incr_hits 585249627
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 2396633334387
STAT bytes_written 1068336598289
STAT limit_maxbytes 2147483648
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT time_in_listen_disabled_us 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT hash_power_level 16
STAT hash_bytes 524288
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT slab_reassign_rescues 1693964
STAT slab_reassign_chunk_rescues 97
STAT slab_reassign_evictions_nomem 0
STAT slab_reassign_inline_reclaim 85547
STAT slab_reassign_busy_items 10795
STAT slab_reassign_busy_deletes 0
STAT slab_reassign_running 0
STAT slabs_moved 34072
STAT lru_crawler_running 0
STAT lru_crawler_starts 16292401
STAT lru_maintainer_juggles 1224560001
STAT malloc_fails 0
STAT log_worker_dropped 0
STAT log_worker_written 0
STAT log_watcher_skipped 0
STAT log_watcher_sent 0
STAT bytes 29817169
STAT curr_items 2804
STAT total_items 211966175
STAT slab_global_page_pool 192
STAT expired_unfetched 33771541
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT evicted_active 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 13256661
STAT crawler_reclaimed 20516908
STAT crawler_items_checked 4188684951
STAT lrutail_reflocked 3658
STAT moves_to_cold 41432828
STAT moves_to_warm 2713
STAT moves_within_lru 171
STAT direct_reclaims 0
STAT lru_bumps_dropped 0
END
```

This doesn't append everytime, so this isn't easy to reproduce.

Do you have some hints I could check?

Thanks by advance and have a good day!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve any of these messages?